# What is the tightest lower bound known for the integrality gap of the Gilmore–Gomory LP for Bin Packing?

Tags: linear-programming, packing, integrality-gap

I know that it has been conjectured that the Gilmore–Gomory LP for 1-D BP (also known as configuration LP) has
Modified Integer Roundup Property, i.e., Opt ≤ ⌈Opt_f⌉ + 1. However, I could not find the best-known lower bound for the integrality gap of the latter LP. Can anyone refer me to such a result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this paper of Hobert and Rothvoss. https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08796

Comment: Thank you very much!